# Find all triples $(a, b, c)$

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Find all triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that

$a^2 + b^2 = n\cdot lcm(a, b) + n^2$

$b^2 + c^2 = n \cdot lcm(b, c) + n^2$

$c^2 + a^2 = n \cdot lcm(c, a) + n^2$

for some positive integer $n$.

Attemp: I think the only solution is $(1,1,1)$.
I used FMID. Not sure of it though

I found an alleged answer: there are infinite solutions (of one parameter)

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com posted the infinite solution set $a=b=c=n$, but deleted the answer for some reason. It seems to be at least a partial answer to the question as stated above. Presumably that is the one-parameter set you found.

Comment: Is it supposed to be the same value of $n$ for all three equations (i.e., you are really finding a quadruple)?